# What happens to the views added via interface builder when memory warning is low?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-management

When we get low memory warning, we release all the views, set outlets to nil, and recreate them all over again.
but for views added in the interface builder, they are only added when we initWithNibName is called.

So, is it in general bad practice to use a lot of views via interface builder or that its automatically taken care of by original `UIViewController` implementation of `didReceiveMemoryWarning(iOS 6+) or viewDidUnload (iOS 5 and below)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior for a `viewcontroller` is to load its view hierarchy when the view property is first accessed and thereafter keep it in memory until the view controller is disposed of. There is no indication that a view created using code is different from one created in Interface Builder. I personally prefer InterfaceBuilder owing to app maintenance since UI code gets complex pretty fast and separating UI elements to the functional aspect of UI elements is a clean bifurcation making it easy for a new programmer to maintain your code base.

But when it comes to releasing memory `didReceiveMemoryWarning` delegate is to be used to  explicitly release the view hierarchy if that additional memory is necessary for your app.

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Add code to clean up any of your own resources that are no longer necessary.
    if ([self.view window] == nil)
    {
        // Add code to preserve data stored in the views that might be
        // needed later.

        // Add code to clean up other strong references to the view in
        // the view hierarchy.
        self.view = nil;
    }
    return;
}
```

note here that we test if the view controller’s view is not onscreen. If the view is associated with a window, then it cleans up any of the view controller’s strong references to the view and its subviews. If the views stored data that needs to be recreated, the implementation of this method should save that data before releasing any of the references to those views. By storing either you can keep it in memory as part of previous viewcontroller's memory or store it in coredate or some other persistent (disk cache etc) way.

The next time the view property is accessed, the view is reloaded exactly as it was the first time. Pictographically it makes perfect sense -

[image]

[[source]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html)